# send copy of message (HTML/PHP)

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I have a php file that needs to send an email to me if the contact section of my contact page has been filled in. And a checkbox whether to send a copy of the message or not. But for some reason if the checkbox is checked, the sender/maker of the message is not receiving a copy of this message in his mailbox.

See code below.

Kind regards

**PHP file being called**

```
<?php 
//////////////////////////
//Specify default values//
//////////////////////////

//Your E-mail

$your_email = 'info@sano-tech.be';

//Default Subject if 'subject' field not specified
$default_subject = 'Van contact formulier';

//Message if 'name' field not specified
$name_not_specified = 'Geef een correcte naam in';

//Message if 'message' field not specified
$message_not_specified = 'Geeft een correcte boodschap in';

//Message if e-mail sent successfully
$email_was_sent = 'Versturen geslaagd!';

//Message if e-mail not sent (server not configured)
$server_not_configured = 'Sorry, mail server niet geconfigeerd';


///////////////////////////
//Contact Form Processing//
///////////////////////////
$errors = array();
if(isset($_POST['message']) and isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['username']))
        $sender_name  = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['username'])));

    if(!empty($_POST['message']))
        $message      = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['message'])));

    if(!empty($_POST['email']))
        $sender_email = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['email'])));

    if(!empty($_POST['subject']))
        $subject      = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['subject'])));

    if(!empty($_POST['nummer']))
        $nummer      = stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['nummer'])));

    $sendcopy = $_POST['sendcopy'];

    //Message if no sender name was specified
    if(empty($sender_name)) {
        $errors[] = $name_not_specified;
    }

    //Message if no message was specified
    if(empty($message)) {
        $errors[] = $message_not_specified;
    }

    $from = (!empty($sender_email)) ? 'From: '.$sender_email : '';

    $subject = (!empty($subject)) ? $subject : $default_subject;

    //$message = (!empty($message)) ? wordwrap($message, 70) : '';

    $message = "
    Onderwerp: $subject

    Naam: $sender_name 

    E-mail: $sender_email 

    Nummer: $nummer

    Boodschap: 

    $message

    ";


    //sending message if no errors
    if(empty($errors)) {
        if($sendcopy == "yes")
        {
            if (mail($your_email, $subject, $message, $from) && mail($sender_email, $subject, $message, $from)) {
                echo $email_was_sent;
            } else {
                $errors[] = $server_not_configured;
                echo implode('<br>', $errors );
            }
        }
        else{
            if (mail($your_email, $subject, $message, $from)) {
                echo $email_was_sent;
            } else {
                $errors[] = $server_not_configured;
                echo implode('<br>', $errors );
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo implode('<br>', $errors );
    }
} else {
    // if "name" or "message" vars not send ('name' attribute of contact form input fields was changed)
    echo '"naam" en "bericht" variabelen zijn niet ontvangen door de server. Gelieve attributen hun "naam" te controleren';
}
?>
```

**HTML (checkbox)**

```
<div class="sc_contact_form_item sc_contact_form_checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="sendcopy" value="yes" id="contact_form_checkbox" checked> Stuur mij een kopie van het bericht
</div>
```

**What I did until now:**

1) add a new mail account: no-reply@domain.be

2) added $headers with 'Reply-To:', 'From:' and 'X-Mailer:'

It's working now and showing the correct addresses in the mail. 
But if the check is made to send a copy the mail still ends up in spam folder. How can I solve this?

Comment: Add the checkbox html to your question.

Comment: Oops, was writing my question in dutch, but can you place the HTML code aswell?

Comment: Can't you just BCC the message to the sender instead of sending it twice?

Comment: Using BCC will expose the email address of the recipient to the recipient of the copy. That's usually not what's intended when using a contact form.

Comment: Using the emailadress entered into the form as sender could be a problem. You are basically sending en email for someone else, from a mailserver that is not authorized to do so. This is usually a big factor to consider your mail as spam. You should use a no-reply-address from your own domain as sender address.

Comment: It's fixed but mail is still getting into spam folder.. Any tips on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

**Mail Fucntion Syntax:**

```
mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);
```

**How add BCC**

Specifies additional headers, like From, Cc, and Bcc. The additional headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).

Note: When sending an email, it must contain a From header. This can be set with this parameter or in the php.ini file.

**Example**

```
 $to = "name@mydomain.com";
 $subject .= "".$emailSubject."";
 $headers .= "Bcc: ".$emailList."\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: no-reply@thepartyfinder.co.uk\r\n" .
     "X-Mailer: php";
     $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
 $message = '<html><body>';
 $message .= 'THE MESSAGE FROM THE FORM';

     if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
     $sent = "Your email was sent!";
     } else {
      $sent = ("Error sending email.");
     }
```

**Why Is My Email Going to The Spam Folder?**

- **Don’t use your email address for the “from” email address.**

If you send a email that is “from” your email (let’s say test@activecampaign.com) and you send it to a contact with the email (test@activecampaign.com) it will most certainly be marked as spam as the “from” and the “to” is the same.

- **Pay attention to the spam filter testing before sending.**
- **Don’t send a single graphic/image**
- **Don’t use a free email address as your “from” email**
- **Test different subjects & email contents**
- **Pay attention to your links in your email**
- **Don’t include links that use link shortening services**
- **Take the time to code your HTML correctly**
- **Remove inactive contacts**
- **Send using a consistent “from” email address**
- **Never include Javascript, form code, or video within your email**
- **Avoid copying anything directly from Microsoft Word, Excel,
  Powerpoint, etc..**

Comment: Things I did:

1) add a new mail account: no-reply@domain.be
2) added $headers with 'Reply-To:', 'From:' and 'X-Mailer:'

It's working now and showing the correct addresses in the mail. But if the check is made to send a copy the mail still ends up in spam folder. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you are sending this through your own mail server you might need to add a "Sender" header which will contain an email address of from your own domain. Gmail will probably be spamming the email because the FROM address is a gmail address but has not been sent from their own server.

Comment: I have put some reason you need to cross check

Comment: Where do you see Gmail?!
Btw none of the reasons apply above.